# SQL — get all rows where column A's date is a multiple of 7 days apart from column B's date

Tags: mysql, sql, date, presto

```
CREATE TABLE table_1 (
  `userid` VARCHAR(2),
  `date_accessed` DATE,
  `rank` INT,
  `country` VARCHAR(2)
);

INSERT INTO table_1
  (`userid`, `date_accessed`, `rank`, `country`)
VALUES
  ('A.', '2019-01-01', 1, 'US'),
  ('B.', '2019-01-02', 1, 'FR'),
  ('A.', '2019-01-03', 2, 'US'),
  ('A.', '2019-01-04', 3, 'US'),
  ('B.', '2019-01-04', 2, 'FR');
```

Here's the fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9F7XPiGtuQAYXQ99HfNJGN/0

And below is an example of the database. I want all the rows where the record date is a multiple of 7 days apart from the start date. The start date and record dates aren't unique; it'll be unique for each country, but both US and FR can have start dates of January 1 and record dates of January 8, for example. In the below table, I'd like to pull the rows where start date is 2019-01-01 and record date is 2019-01-08, for example.

```
| start_date | num_people | record_date | rating | country |
| ---------- | ---------- | ----------- | ------ | ------- |
| 2019-01-01 | 275        | 2019-01-08  | 4      | FR      |
| 2019-01-02 | 150        | 2019-01-10  | 4      | FR      |
| 2019-01-03 | 175        | 2019-01-09  | 5      | FR      |
| 2019-01-04 | 300        | 2019-01-11  | 2      | FR      |
| 2019-01-01 | 100        | 2019-01-08  | 8.5    | US      |
| 2019-01-03 | 50         | 2019-01-10  | 5.5    | US      |
| 2019-01-03 | 50         | 2019-01-17  | 5      | US      |

---
```

I want to do this out to 84 days (every 7 days/every week for 12 weeks).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need the difference and a modulo function.

In MySQL:

```
select t.*
from t
where mod(datediff(record_date, start_date), 7) = 0;
```

In PrestoDB, that wouldbe:

```
where mod(date_diff('day', start_date, record_date), 7) = 0
```

Comment: @MichaelHauptmann . . . It is unlikely that an index would help with this query.  Assuming the days are evenly distributed, the query would retrieve about one in seven rows -- so it is not highly selective.